# Scale space blob detection using opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, computer-vision

i am new in image processing and computer vision and i would like to detect blobs in an image using Laplacian of Gaussian with different scale spaces. The following links explain in detail.
[http://www.cs.utah.edu/~jfishbau/advimproc/project1/](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Ejfishbau/advimproc/project1/)
[http://www.cs.utah.edu/~manasi/coursework/cs7960/p1/project1.html](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Emanasi/coursework/cs7960/p1/project1.html)
So far by using opencv2 i have managed to get the images, apply the Gaussian filter with various kernels and apply the Laplacian filter. The i multiply with sigma squared the whole image to amplify the signal (see description in links) and then i apply a threshhold. The next step is to detect local maxima and minima so i can get the blob center and be able to draw circles, but i am not sure how to do it and whether the image processing i have done so far is correct. Here is my code:

```
int main(){

    image1 = imread("butterfly.jpg",0);

    drawing1 = imread("butterfly.jpg");

    blobDetect(image1,drawing1);
waitKey();
    return 0;
}

void blobDetect(Mat image, Mat drawing){

    int ksize = 1;
    int n =1;

    Mat result[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    cv::GaussianBlur(image,result[i],cv::Size(ksize,ksize),ksize/3,0);
    n+=1;
    ksize = 2*n-1;
    }

    ksize = 1;
    n =1;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    cv::Laplacian(result[i],result[i],CV_8U,ksize,1,0);
    n+=1;
        ksize = 2*n-1;
   }

   ksize = 1;
   int cols = image.cols;
   int rows = image.rows;
   for(int a=0; a<10; a++){
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        //uchar* data = result[a].ptr<uchar>(rows);
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            result[a].at<uchar>(i,j) *= (ksize/3)*(ksize/3);                
        }   
    }
    ksize++;
    ksize = 2*ksize-1;
}
    

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    cv::threshold(result[i], result[i], 100, 255, 0);
}
    
}
```

[image: This is the expected result]

This is the expected result

Thanks

Comment: First I feel the need to clarify one point: you are not using "different scale spaces", you are using a single space-scale which in this question is the gaussian (or linear) scale-space. From it and based on the works by Lindeberg these links are suggesting the combined use of a Laplacian filter to attempt to find blobs across scales. From there many possibilities exist, one of them would be by considering the regional maxima present in two "adjacent" scales as being a blob, so a circle can be derived from it. So, is your problem related to scale-space or regional maxima/minima ?

Answer (score 0):

After you detect contours, you can use

```
minEnclosingCircle()
```

Even better is to check out this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

Comment: I cannot use contours that would be easy, i have to follow a certain algorithm described in the links provided.

Comment: When you calculate/find/get the points for blobs, you don't have to create or use contours, minEnclosingCircle() works with points, not with contours, so it would work for you.


http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle


Basically you give the function "points", it gives you back the center and radius of minimum enclosing circle, then you can draw circle easily.

Comment: Basically my problem is that i don't know how to find the points that are the center of a blob in the processed images and i am not sure whether my image processing (Laplacian of Gaussian) is correct.

Comment: Both `minEnclosingCircle` and the linked tutorial are truly irrelevant for the problem. The regional minima in these images are mostly single points (i.e., one pixel), thus there is no point in using the former function. From these kind of functions, the only relevant one would be `circle` -- which does nothing more than drawing a circle of some radius at a given center. But the problem being solved is not about drawing circles, it is about computing regional maxima/minima.

Comment: He wanted to find the central point of the circle so minEnclosingCircle is relevant also the tutorial. So draw a circle and maybe you can make-up the center point of it. This is a simple thing, just be logical and do not get it complicated.

Comment: @SelimArikan do you have any idea about the output that the procedure being used gives ?

Comment: @mmgp yes, the procedure gives you the center point and radius of the enclosing circle of the given blob (given as points). That is what he needs.

Comment: @SelimArikan I have the exact same assignement, a blob is not a point, a blob can have different sizes...... unless if points have from x1 to x2 and from y1 to y2 minEnclosingCircle is not at all relevant because you can have a point with x,y that needs to be circled with let's say radius1 and a different point of a blob with x1,y1 that needs to be circled with radius2
if you have a few points on the blob yes, but local maxima (blob center) is only one point....